# how to handle non english key presses

Tags: javascript, internationalization

When I switch my keyboard layout to hebrew and press a character, it is received in the kepress event as is. For example, clicking `ה` (the v key), then `e.which` is 1492. However, when I do a combination the key is the english key. So for `alt+ה` `e.which` is 86. So the event looks like `alt+v`

This is a pain if I want to create a function that accepts key combinations and callbacks and registers the callbacks but also shows a documentation of the callbacks, since if I register `alt+ה`, then when I press the combination it will look like `alt+v` and it wouldn't match the registered combinations. But if I register `alt+v`, then the documentation will be awkward.

So my question boils down to whether one of the following is possible:

1. knowing which key actually was pressed (meaning, knowing that `ה` was pressed together with `alt` and not `v`)
2. mapping between the hebrew characters (or any non-english) to their physical english counterparts, so when my function receives `alt+ה` it will convert it to `alt+v` for the callback lookup.

Of course I want something generic, that will work for any language, not list just the hebrew alphabet.

Comment: Although badly supported, W3C has a current [working draft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) on the topic.

Comment: Altough it's just an educated guess, but maybe one of the layers above (keyboard, OS) makes this conversion on the fly before it would even reach the browser, to allow consistent interface for common operations (copy, paste, cut, select all, save, etc.), which actually makes sense, so if you find this behavior consistent enough across systems, then go with the awkward documentation, and be happy that you don't have to handle every languages keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not care if it is alt-ה or alt-v, you want to perform the same operation on both cases.
2. If it is not identified, it is not identified anywhere, so your function will get alt-v as well.
3. if your function gets something ("Alt", "ה") you should create an object for conversion.
   var conv= { 'ה': 'v'; 'ש': 'a',...}